# Apache Spark ML Pipeline: filter empty rows in dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

In my Spark ML Pipeline (Spark 2.3.0) I use `RegexTokenizer` like this:

```
val regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("words")
      .setMinTokenLength(3)
```

It transforms `DataFrame` to the one with arrays of words, for example:

```
text      | words
-------------------------
a the     | [the]
a of to   | []
big small | [big,small]
```

How to filter rows with empty `[]` arrays?
Should I create custom transformer and pass it to pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SQLTransformer`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer

val emptyRemover = new SQLTransformer().setStatement(
  "SELECT * FROM __THIS__ WHERE size(words) > 0"
)
```

which can applied directly

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a the", Seq("the")), ("a of the", Seq()), 
  ("big small", Seq("big", "small"))
).toDF("text", "words")

emptyRemover.transform(df).show
```

```
+---------+------------+
|     text|       words|
+---------+------------+
|    a the|       [the]|
|big small|[big, small]|
+---------+------------+
```

or used in a `Pipeline`.

Nonetheless I would consider twice before using this in Spark ML process. Tools normally used downstream, like `CountVectorizer`, can handle empty input just fine:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer

val vectorizer = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("features")
```

```
+---------+------------+-------------------+                 
|     text|       words|           features|
+---------+------------+-------------------+
|    a the|       [the]|      (3,[2],[1.0])|
| a of the|          []|          (3,[],[])|
|big small|[big, small]|(3,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])|
+---------+------------+-------------------+
```

and lack of presence of certain words, can often provide useful information.

Answer (score -2):

```
df
  .select($text, $words)
  .where(size($words) > 0)
```

Comment: I cannot do this because I use pipeline. I can create custom transformer to wrap this code but I want to know if there are another options

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.